# iTunes 12.5+ plist setting for View As -> Songs by default?

Tags: macos, itunes

I find the the default view of songs to "Songs" too white and it's irritating / abominable to view `Playlist` that way. It does't show enough details for my taste so I'd rather see something else than the current default view (Playlist):
[image: playlist view]

Instead, I would like to see content directly as the Songs view instead:
[image: songs view]

Does anyone know of a plist setting (in `com.apple.iTunes.plist`) to change the default view of songs to "Songs" instead of the `Playlist` setting?

Comment: Could you provide pictures showing what you mean? As far as I'm aware, whatever defaults were, they are overwritten by 'whatever you last did' as soon as you do it.

Comment: Added images as per request.

Comment: & you want a prefs tweak to make all **new** playlists to have the 2nd example view? If so, understood - though idk how, I just swap mine afterwards :/ Cmd/J btw for view options, same as Finder, but idk how to override defaults.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Not just new, but old as well. This new blinding white color vs the custom colors defined by album art before is very difficult.

Comment: Actually, I hated the 'blurry album art' version. I like my lists to be lists, not 'arty' ;-) I'd actually forgotten it used to do that, so glad it's gone. [But, horses for courses & I hope someone knows the answer to your question. Good luck.]

Comment: Well, for me it's not about the artsy aspect of it, but a DARK aspect.  I have iTunes up all of the time on one of my displays (I have multiple heads on my main system) and it's like having a sun blaring all day and night. :)

Comment: Just adding my findings here, even though they were not complete. In iTunes 7 (and maybe newer), there was a setting called "Set iTunes global view options" which would do just what it says - not perfect but just what I would personally want. This settings has disappeared. I was able to trace down the defaults write for it (`defaults write com.apple.Music remember-view-settings-for-each-source -bool FALSE`) but it does nothing. So the hunt continues.

Comment: @horstwilhelm have you given Apple feedback on this via their Feedback Assistant.app? I have been having a terrible time getting them to reply over the last couple years, but it sure beats other methods...

Comment: @ylluminate thanks for the heads up, I just did that, hope it will help.

Comment: Let us hope. There is so much that needs attention now. I just keep using iTunes via Retroactive for the time being with Ventura since Music is still a steaming pile of stank. I wish they'd get their heads out of their rears when it comes to iWork and allowing multi selections as used to be the case before the rewrite. I was able to do many tasks in about half the time I can now in Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another useful option is to set up a keyboard shortcut through System Preferences (⌘S is available).

Since the menu item "Songs" is used in multiple places, you have to use the full menu path when setting up the shortcut: `View->View As->Songs`

Comment: While this isn't exactly the solution I was looking for, it's a very pragmatic and approachable solution. This works relatively nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to change the default view mode for new playlists, but you can run a script like this in Script Editor to change the view mode of all existing playlists:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    user playlists whose special kind is none and smart is false
    repeat with p in result
        set view of browser window 1 to p
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
            click menu item "Songs" of menu 1 of menu item "View As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

I use a script like the one below to create most new playlists. It requires GNU `xargs` and `readlink` which you can install by running `brew install findutils coreutils`.

```
osascript -e'on run {a}
    set l to {}
    repeat with f in (get paragraphs of a)
        set end of l to POSIX file f
    end repeat
    tell application "iTunes"
        if number of l is 1 then
            tell application "Finder" to set n to name of (item 1 of l as alias)
            delete playlists whose name is n
            set p to make new user playlist with properties {name:n}
        else
            set p to make new user playlist
        end if
        with timeout of 0 seconds -- don't exit with an error if the add command takes over 20 seconds
            add l to p
        end
        set view of browser window 1 to p
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
            click menu item "Songs" of menu 1 of menu item "View As" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end run' "$(printf %s\\n "${@-$(cat)}"|gxargs -rd\\n greadlink -f)"
```

If the System Events application is not on the list of applications in "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility", the script above results in an error like this: `636:751: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)`.

Comment: Good stuff, really glad to see someone who cares about this and has similar needs. While it's not a "perfect fit", seeing this after so long is a breath of fresh air. Wish Apple would stop getting it's priorities so screwed up nowadays.