# How to set up App Shortcuts for Music.app in Catalina?

Tags: itunes, keyboard, catalina, music, music.app

I'd like to set up System Preferences Keyboard Shortcuts to activate Music's View as Songs via a <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, but it's not activating after setting it up.

To clarify, my goal is to activate this in Music.app:
[image: menu-item]

In System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts I've set the following:
[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't work as it used to for iTunes.app.

Comment: @allan since no one read the previous remarks and clearly indicated purpose behind my previous question, I went ahead and created a new one here that just eliminates any background reading.

Answer (score 1):

I have just verified this feature actually does still work but you aren't using it properly, there is no need for the `->` syntax, I am unsure where this comes from but I have never seen that used.

The correct way to create this shortcut is as shown below:

1. Open System Preferences.app
2. Navigate to 'Keyboard'
3. Select 'Shortcuts'
4. Choose 'App Shortcuts'
5. Add a shortcut using the <kbd>+</kbd> button.
6. Choose the app 'Music'
7. Set the menu title to the text name of the menu title 'as Songs' ignoring where in the menu bar it is.
8. Set a shortcut by clicking the field, then pressing the keys.
9. Finalise by clicking 'Add'.

*You can verify this has worked as the shortcut will be shown in the menu*

How it should look: 
[image]

> **Note:** It is not possible to distinguish between identically named menu items in the same application.

Comment: This worked in practice previously (tested and worked at least up to 10.14.x Mojave): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364340/13220

Comment: Super interestingm I did not know that. hopefully this works now. I guess it's possibly an issue with it being a Marzipan application but I don't wanna faff about verifying that right now.

Comment: Well poo... unfortunately this did not work still (and btw, I had tried this method you note before as well along with the method I noted before... :S ): https://p153.p0.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/NQuvPyed/setting.jpg

Comment: That menu item only appears in certain places like playlists, are you sure its just you are in the wrong part of the application? Is the menu item actually visible in the menu bar? I tested this on my machine 10.15.3 and it's fine but only works when the menu item is visible which isn't all the time.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. Music.app is focussed, the actual album is focussed, and I can click view and see that item, here's an example by using MenuMate for context: https://p153.p0.n0.cdn.getcloudapp.com/items/2NurLG5Q/context.jpg - and so pressing the key combo in this situation does not activate the menu item and simply gives an alert sound.

Comment: Very strange, might be worth creating a new user and testing this again. Also for sanity sakes checking that Menu Mate, Bartender and other applications like that are not running when testing just in case!

Comment: Hrm. Sad it worked fine with everything just a couple weeks ago prior to my "upgrade" to Crapolina. If Apple would have not pushed me into the upgrade, telling me that some troublesome bugs were fixed on 10.15 then I would have (and should have) just stayed with Mojave until someone wakes up at Apple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103983/discussion-between-unknowndomain-and-ylluminate).